# Salesforce Quickbooks Integration using REST API

Tags: salesforce, quickbooks

We are looking to develop our in-house custom integration between Salesforce & Quickbooks.

So far we got to the point that we need to develop some Federated App on Quickooks platform.

Is there any way to access/update Quickbooks data from Salesforce using REST API without developing app on IPP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the old QuickBooks SDK.  It's free, and XML based.  But it will eventually be retired, in favor of IPP.

The next thing from IPP (Intuit Partner Platform) is Intuit Anywhere (IA), which avoids you having to do a full federated implemented.  Intuit Anywhere is 100 times easier to integrate than federated, mainly because you manage your own billing and user management.  There is a cost to use their Rest API, it's $5 a month.

We do both.  We have a legacy SDK app that works great for the QuickBooks desktop version.  We also have an Intuit Anywhere sync that we use for QuickBooks Online.  Note: you could use the SDK or IA for either.

Questions: Why not use use the standard salesforce DataSync link from Pervasive?

Also, does it have to be salesforce?  CRM's like [Method CRM](http://www.methodintegration.com) have the syncing seamlessly built in, so you don't have to mess with anything.

Paul

Comment: Thanks Paul! We are looking to achieve custom field syncing so I am not sure DataSynch can help. Yes, it needs to be with Salesforce.

I am trying to figure out some way where Salesforce will invoke REST API of QB and access/update it via REST API. Do I need to publish application to use IA? I am basically looking to use data service of Quickbooks similar to SDK API instead of developing some app with IPP.

Comment: You currently need to publish the app to use IA.  But they will soon expand it to handle custom apps. It's in their best interest, since right now all custom inhouse developers have to resort to the SDK which Intuit is trying to  get people off.  Intuit has stated that custom apps on IPP will come soon.  If you use the SDK, you'll want to put your app on the same computer that hosts QuickBooks and pulls data from salesforce.

Comment: For developers looking to build a reusable product, note that the $5 a month is actually [$5 a month for each "connection"](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Managing_Your_App/2000_Billing_for_IA), where a "connection" is defined as a user connecting their company to your app. So if you had 10 users, you would be paying $50 a month.

Comment: Mark - for further clarification, let's make sure everyone reading this knows the difference between users vs companies.  So let's say you build 1 app. And you get 10 different companies using your app. That's 10 connections at $5 each, so $50. Now, let's say that each of those companies had 5 users of your app and 5 users in QuickBooks. It would still be $50 total. In other words you are charged per company connection, not per users within the company.

Answer (score 0):

We have used AppSynergy's federated integration with QuickBooks to create an employee facing web app that reads and writes live QuickBooks data (mostly purchase orders in our case) based on data from other systems.